# Activating language client Q# Language Extension: Q# Language Client failed to activate

Tags: q#, qdk

When I load my Q# solution in Visual Studio I get a notification that the activation of the Q# language client failed with the following message: `The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete.`

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.5.4) together with Microsoft Quantum Development Kit extension (version 0.28.263081).

If I open the same project in Visual Studio Code the message `Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.` is printed recurringly at least once a seconds in the output pane when I select "Q# Language Extension" in the drop-down.